# QueryTables.Add changes row height

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following..

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurlname, Destination:=DataSheet.Range(Cells(row_stock + iMax, 29), Cells(row_stock + 199, 29)))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

After excution, the rows in question have their height modified from what was originally 15 to 11.25 evidently the minimum for the selected font.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Does it happen in more than one workbook?  What version of Excel?  I'm wondering if there's a default template, but that would only apply to one workbook.

Comment: @doug: Very old excel, too cheap to buy new one.  How would I know if there is a "default template"?

Comment: If it's very old, then I don't think that's the issue.  Not sure, but think it would only apply to 2007 onwards.  In those versions, you'd see different templates available in the ribbon.  I'm still curious if it happens in all workbooks or just one.  But I doubt I'm barking up the right tree :)

Comment: You might not be able to prevent it, but seems like it would be pretty straightforward to set the height back after creating the querytable.

Comment: @Tim: The row height seems to vary.  I will try it on a newer excel tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why querytables changes the row heights or how to prevent it but I did manage to change things so that the querytables results were placed in a different worksheet.  Copying the cells from that sheet to the main sheet left the row height unchanged.